# How do I create a state of "don't assign anything to variable" if WP_Error throws an error?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, errors, wp-error

I have this code to scrape Instagram pictures from a given account:

```
<?php

class Scrape_Instagram {

    private $images = array();

    public function __construct( $username ) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    private function build_endpoint() {
        /**
        * Builds the endpoint for the Instagram API, provided the username from constructor.
        * @param $end_cursor    Used in case the user wants more pictures to be scrapped.
        */
        return 'https://www.instagram.com/' . trim( strtolower( $this->username ) ) . '/?__a=1';
    }

    private function get_json() {
        /**
        * GET's the data from Instagram, provided the endpoint.
        */
        $request = wp_remote_get( $this->build_endpoint() );

        if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'site-down', esc_html__( 'Instagram may be down. Unable to communicate.', '_s') );
        }

        elseif( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) !== 200 ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'invalid-response', esc_html__( 'Got an invalid response.', '_s') );
        }

        else {
            return wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
        }
    }

    private function get_data() {
        /**
        * Ingests the data from get_json() then converts / decodes into an array.
        */
        $data = json_decode( $this->get_json(), true);

        if ( is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'invalid-data', esc_html__( 'Something is wrong. Did you enter the right username?', '_s' ) );
        } else {
            return $data;
        }
    }

    protected function get_links() {
        /**
        * Based on the array generated from get_data(), some nodes have resulted that contain information about
        * each photo the user has, as such, we'll loop through each photo and access any data.
        * @see ['user']['media']['nodes'] - individual node / image.
        */
        $response = $this->get_data();

        foreach( $response['user']['media']['nodes'] as $node ) {
            // Check if type is video, if not, set default image
            array_push( $this->images, $node['thumbnail_src'] );
        }
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function get_instagram_photos_links() {
        return $this->get_links();
    }
}
```

There are several `WP_Error` to supposedly handle errors that would come from the variables it checks for.

So, within the method `get_json()`, I have:

```
private function get_json() {
    /**
    * GET's the data from Instagram, provided the endpoint.
    */
    $request = wp_remote_get( $this->build_endpoint() );

    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'site-down', esc_html__( 'Instagram may be down. Unable to communicate.', '_s') );
    }

    elseif( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) !== 200 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid-response', esc_html__( 'Got an invalid response.', '_s') );
    }

    else {
        return wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    }
}
```

Which should stop `$data` from gaining any value if it fails. What I want / thought it'd do is (even though I recognize I first declared `$data`):

`Hey, WordPress, see this $data? Yea, don't assign anything to it if these WP_Errors say it's bad. Just drop it and break loop.`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't happen and I've built a widget for this, using:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Instagram Widget
*/

add_action( 'widget_init', 'custom_widget_instagram_pictures');
register_widget( 'custom_widget_instagram_pictures' );

class custom_widget_instagram_pictures extends Wp_Widget {

    /**
    * Setup the Widget
    */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname'     => 'custom_widget_instagram_pictures',
                            'description'   => esc_html__('A widget to display instagram photos.', '_s') 
                            );

        $control_ops = array('id_base'      => 'custom_widget_instagram_pictures');

        parent::__construct( 'custom_widget_instagram_pictures', __('_s: Instagram Widget', '_s_simple_image_widget'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title              = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $username           = isset( $instance['username'] ) ? $instance['username'] : '';
        $profile_link       = isset( $instance['profile_link'] ) ? $instance['profile_link'] : '';

        echo ent2ncr( $before_widget );

        if ( $title ) {
            echo ent2ncr( $before_title . $title . $after_title );
        }
        ?>
        <div class="instagram-widget">
            <ul class="instagram-widget-list">
                <?php if( $username ) {
                    $instagram_object = new Scrape_Instagram($username);
                    $instagram_links = $instagram_object->get_instagram_photos_links();
                    foreach( $instagram_links as $link ) { ?>
                        <li class="instagram-thumb">
                            <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><img src="<?php echo $link ?>"/></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php }

                } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php if( 'on' == $profile_link ) : ?>
            <button class="instagram-widget-profile-link"><a href="<?php echo 'https://www.instagram.com/' . $username; ?>"><?php echo $username ?></a></button>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        echo ent2ncr( $after_widget );
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance['title']          = ( isset( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['username']       = ( isset( $new_instance['username'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['username'] ) : '';
        $instance['profile_link']   = ( isset( $new_instance['profile_link'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['profile_link'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults = array(  'title'         => '',
                            'username'      => '',
                            'profile_link'  => '',
                        );

        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>
        <!-- Form for Title -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Widget Title:<strong>(Leave Blank to Hide)</strong></label>
            <br>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title'];?>" />
        </p>

        <!-- Form for Link -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'username' ); ?>">Username:</label>
            <br>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'username' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'username' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['username'];?>" />
        </p>

        <!-- The checkbox -->
        <p>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance[ 'profile_link' ], 'on' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'profile_link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'profile_link' ); ?>" /> 
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'profile_link' ); ?>">Show Instagram Button?</label>
        </p>
    <?php

    }
}

?>
```

And if I enter a wrong username, say: "kinfolk53252395932", it just throws this:

[image: The error]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the line giving you the error is rather this one

```
$data = json_decode( $this->get_json(), true);
```

Like this (untested) it should work:

```
private function get_data() {
    /**
    * Ingests the data from get_json() then converts / decodes into an array.
    */
    $json = $this->get_json();
    if (is_wp_error($json)) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid-data', esc_html__( 'Something is wrong. Did you enter the right username?', '_s' ) );
    }

    $data = json_decode( $json, true);

    if ( is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid-data', esc_html__( 'Something is wrong. Did you enter the right username?', '_s' ) );
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

I'm actually not too familiar with `WP_Error`, but aren't errors supposed to be thrown instead of returned?

Why does it work like this? Well, the PHP error message tells you what goes wrong

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

```
json_decode( $this->get_json(),
             ^ should be a string but is an object
```

From your code we know, that it is an object of `WP_Error`, because that is what you return from `get_json()`.

I guess the important thing to take away: check for an error inside a variable/return before you use it.

Comment: I was thinking there'd be a "Raise" or somethig, but nope, that's how they do it, it seems.

Comment: Somehow, this works. Can you please explain what happened here and why splitting the two methods into one worked?

Comment: @JonathanGuerin I've added a small explanation. Does this help?